# How to convert list of list to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, python, html, sql-server-2008

I am retrieving  from Sql-server database list of bank account in Python

```
Alllist=select_from_db_service(sql,[1],organization)
   if len(Alllist)>0:
        for row in Alllist:      
           info_list.append((list(row)))
```

then i am rendering it to an HTML page:
   return render(request,'app/reporting.html',

```
{'info_list':info_list,'start_date':start_date,'end_date':end_date})
```

in the HTML page i have two drop list inputs Company and Account_id

```
<input  type="text" list='List_of_Companies' data-search-in="Company" id="Input1" name="Companyname"  placeholder="Choose a Company"  value="{{ Company}}" >

<input  type="text" list='List_of_Accounts' data-search-in="Account" id="Input2" name="Accountname"  placeholder="Choose an Account ID" value="{{ Account_Id}}" hidden>
        <br>  <br>
```

Both of them greeting the data from info_list return from Python using HTML Datalist:

```
    <datalist id="List_of_Companies">
 <select id="filenamelist" size="5"  class="select">
     {% for Company in  info_list %}
     <option value="{{ Company.3 }}">{{  Company.3 }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
     </select>
 </datalist>




   <datalist id="List_of_Accounts">
 <select id="filenamelist" size="5"  class="select">
     {% for Company in  info_list %}
     <option value="{{ Company.0 }}" data-value="{{  Company.3 }}" > {{  Company.3 }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
     </select>
 </datalist>
```

Now pending on the values i get from the Company input i want to present only relevant inputs in the account id input which i am able to do and to show an HTML DataTalbe with only the relevant entries in info_list base on the inputs the user choose on the Company.

I tried the following,In the HTML page in Form tag:

```
<input  type="text" id="DataTableInput" value="{{ info_list}}" hidden />
```

In JavaScript i tried:

```
var dataSet = document.getElementById("DataTableInput").value; 
console.log('DataSet' + dataSet)
```

The output looks like :

```
DataSet[['39 XXX, 'EUR', 'CS', Company_name', 4, '01-jan-2019'], ['12 XXX',, 'USD, 'CS', 'Company_name2', 5, '01-jan-2019'],
['34 XXX', 'USD', 'CS', Company_name2', 5, '01-jan-2019'],…..]
```

Now i want to iterate over this array and filter only the ones the have the right company name from the input ,but i cant accesses the elements,
thanks in advance,
Nir

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you access the element ? if `console.log(dataSet[2])` give you the company name you should be able to do something like this :

```js
function filterByCompanyName(array, name) {
  //assuming index 3 is always the company name of course
  return array.filter(item => item[3] == name);
}

let givenArray = [['39 XXX', 'EUR', 'CS', 'Company_name', 4, '01-jan-2019'], ['12 XXX', 'USD', 'CS', 'Company_name2', 5, '01-jan-2019'],
['34 XXX', 'USD', 'CS', 'Company_name2', 5, '01-jan-2019']];

console.log(filterByCompanyName(givenArray, 'Company_name2'));
```

Comment: My bad, i have edited my question ,console.log('DataSet' + dataSet)
gives me :DataSet[['39 XXX, 'EUR', 'CS', Company_name', 4, '01-jan-2019'], ['12 XXX',, 'USD, 'CS', 'Company_name2', 5, '01-jan-2019'],
['34 XXX', 'USD', 'CS', Company_name2', 5, '01-jan-2019'],…..]  , Dataset[2] gives me:DataSet'

Comment: yes so you just have to use the above function with dataset right ?

Comment: I am geeting Uncaught TypeError: array.filter is not a function

Comment: it means the first parameter you gave to the function is not an array. Could you check again dataSet is an array ?

Comment: DataSet as i wrote above is a list of list python object return into HTML page, when i am using consol.log in order to see what is return i am getting :['39 XXX', 'EUR', 'CS', 'Company_name', 4, '01-jan-2019'], ['12 XXX', 'USD', 'CS', 'Company_name2', 5, '01-jan-2019'],
['34 XXX', 'USD', 'CS', 'Company_name2', 5, '01-jan-2019']]; i am not sure it is a javascript array

Comment: Did you try to do `let jsArray = Array.from(dataSet)` ?

Comment: Hi, found the solution ,  it was the way i construct the list in Python

Comment: Your example array format is wrong, check your datalist is well generated before trying to get the value with javascript, i guess your problem comes from the way you constrcut your data

Comment: Ok nice, could you add an answer to your post for more visibility then ?

Comment: r = [dict((row.cursor_description[i][0], value)  for i, value in enumerate(newrow)) for newrow in Alllist]   
json_output = json.dumps(r)